# How to join a tables and show name from linking table

Tags: mysql

I have table `questions` that looks like this:

[image]

And notice the last column `quiz_id`. That number is is representing a subject from table `quizzes`, and `quizzes` looks like this:

[image]

With more rows, 2,3,4,5,6.. and so on.

## Question:

How do I join the tables so that instead of a number in a query, the name shows from corresponding number from `quizzes`.

So `SELECT * FROM questions` will not show:

[image]

But instead:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `quizzes` is your *parent table* and `questions` is a *child*, i.e. you have a foreign key constraint between these two in a 1:n (one-to-many) relationship.

You need to *join* these tables based *on* the quiz_id:

```
select questions.id, questions.content, questions.source, quizzes.name
  from questions join quizzes on questions.quiz_id=quizzes.id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT questions.id, questions.content, questions.source, quizzes.name
FROM questions
INNER JOIN quizzes ON (questions.quizid = quizzes.id)
```